# Convert from ISO to custom format pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I would to like to convert ISO format date string to a custom format. I don't see any functions in Pig 0.10. I saw functions like DATE_TIME from Amazon but they seem to open only to Amazon customers. Can someone please help if the there is a UDF for conversion like ISO to customformat ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's only the opposite conversion available directly in the Piggybank:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/

Nothing turns up on GitHub, ...